# How to sum a list of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, sum

New to python and got stuck.

I produced the below code to sum the cube of the digits of a given number. i.e. 123 -> 1 + 8 + 27 = 36

```
# split_cube used to seperate digits in number and cube in an array
# i.e 32 -> [27, 8]

def split_cube(n):
    return [int(x)**3 for x in str(n)]

# change n to number and run for sum of digits cubed
n = 123

a = split_cube(n)

def sum_of_digits_cubed(y):
    print(sum(a))

sum_of_digits_cubed(a)
```

output 36.

I now want to make a code that does this for all 3 digit number.

I've been able to write a code to list all the arrays, however I don't know how to sum them.

```
# split_cube used to seperate digits from number
# and cube in an array i.e 32 -> [27, 8]
# range is 100 - 999

def list_split_cube(n):
        for n in range(100,1000,1):
                print([int(x)**3 for x in str(n)])

a = list_split_cube(n)

print(a)
```

first 4 output is, it goes on:

```
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 8]
[1, 0, 27]
```

However I want a list like this where it now sums the array. i.e.
1
2
9
28
etc.

However when I try toadd sum commands it errors because it iterates I believe.

My next aim will then be to only display the list where the sum of there digits cubed is equal to the number. i.e. 153 -> 1 + 125 + 27. However cant yet get to the point where it's showing a list of the summed array.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function you've already defined instead of copying and pasting it into your loop; the whole point of defining a function is that once you've defined it, it becomes a shortcut to do whatever is defined in the body of the function so you don't have to copy and paste that same code everywhere.

You can also apply the `sum` function to that list just like you did in `sum_of_digits_cubed`:

```
def split_cube(n):
    return [int(x)**3 for x in str(n)]

for n in range(100, 1000):
    print(sum(split_cube(n)))
```

prints:

```
1
2
9
28
65
126
217
344
513
730
2
...etc
```

For the next part (only printing the numbers where `n` is equal to `sum(split_cubed(n))`, you just need an `if`:

```
for n in range(100, 1000):
    if n == sum(split_cube(n)):
        print(n)
```

prints:

```
153
370
371
407
```

Comment: when I do this I get the below error code:

```----> 5     print(sum(split_cube(n)))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable```

Comment: nevermind. I just copied into a new notebook and it seemed to work. but when using a new [in] on the previous notebook didnt work. Not sure why that is. Thanks for the solution.I think I was over complicating it

Comment: You had probably assigned an int value to either `sum` or `split_cube` earlier in that session.  Never do `sum = ...` if you want to be able to use the actual `sum` function later on!

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Thanks I'm very new, literally second day trying coding :) I think maybe in that case my previous attempts might have even worked if I cleared the previous ones, albeit if it did it was less tidy than your solution. Cheers for the explanation